# How to get Barcode data from android marshmallow handheld devices

Tags: android, phonegap

I am having android **marshmallow** handheld devices. The device hardware having the `barcode` scanning functionality. So, How to get the `barcode` scan results in my app after scanning the `barcode` from the handheld devices. I need the code for both android native and phone gap. thanks in advance

Comment: u can use some library for barcode scanning

Comment: any library which you suggest

Comment: journeyapps:zxing

Comment: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

Comment: Scan is done in android hardware like fingerprint in marshmallow . Just i need get scanned data in my application